# Mule and Gradle build tool

Tags: mule

Questions:

1) Can I use Mule(3.7) application with Gradle, is it fully supported?

2) Continuous Integration runs with Gradle and Jenkins for other non Mule based applications in our organization, can I have local Maven build with Anypoint studio and CI with Gradle? Is there any issues with this kind of configuration, since Mule is well built with Maven build tool?

I have gone through the Gradle plugin for Mule [here](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-gradle-plugin)

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you two build systems on a single application ?

Comment: @Sudarshan, Mule application works good with Maven build. But, organization have CI with Jenkins and Graddle. Since Mule is more align towards Maven, I thought of using Maven in local dev environment and commit the code in git, once git is submits code to Jenkins, then let the build trigger in Jenkins with Graddle which is standard build tool used in our organization. I can make Maven build in Jenkins, but for my Mule based application will have separate build standards than other existing projects.

Comment: bekur @Sudarshan:  Planning to use Gradle for my Mule Project first time out from maven. How do you  see using MULE+ Gradle. Is that going great? . Looking for real world usecase feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @star I think you can make it work, but you will have to put in a fair bit of work for all the maven plugins that Mulesoft have developed for eg: the org.mule.tools.maven plugin for cloudhub deployments

Comment: @Sudarshan: Seems like we have Gradle plugin but the mulesoft not officially gonna support it. Im using On-premise version. In this case still I need to workout more for gradle Plugins. Have you used Gradle and how was the go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it but it is not a MuleSoft officially supported tool. [Here](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-gradle-plugin) is the link to the GitHub project. The problem with using two different build tools is that the configuration will probably get out of sync at some point. Anypoint Studio doesn't provide a very complete Maven support anyway, so you could just use Gradle and update Studio dependencies manually or try using an Eclipse Gradle plugin. This can still be out of sync, but will have to maintain only Gradle config.

Comment: you mentioned '...Gradle plugin. This can still be out of sync, but will....' how this will be out of sync?

Comment: If you need to add a new dependency you need to remember to change it in both places.

Comment: how do I add graddle eclipse plugin to Anypoint studio, since I couldnot find Market place in Anypoint Studio.

Comment: You can try adding the update site of the plugin or install it manually, but I haven't tried that.